# Laptop screen is flickering, how can I diagnose if its the LCD/backlight or the inverter or something else

Tags: lcd

My laptop is the Acer Swift SF714-52T. Recently, I started noticing a ~10 Hz flicker on the screen, like someone is swapping back and forth from 100% brightness to 90% brightness.  Sometimes it appears strongly, sometimes more subtly.  This happens on both battery and AC power.  It is not dependent on the position of the screen and giving it a gentle tap doesn't affect the flickering.

I figured it was a software problem first.  I tried everything I could find online about flickering screens. I tried uninstalling the screen in Device Manager, I tried reinstalling the display drivers, I tried seeing if I could change my displays refresh rate (I can't, it's locked to 60 Hz), and nothing has worked.

I figured it's a hardware issue, so I RMA'd the laptop, and I included instructions in the box on how I've been getting the flicker to appear more strongly.  I got the laptop back and the notes on the report said that the technician was unable to reproduce the problem. I thought I was going crazy so I asked my girlfriend to look at the screen to see if it was flickering and she confirmed that it was.

So I wired up a crude light meter with my know-how of electronics and recorded the severity and frequency of flickering, and this is what I found.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra8ts.png

I set the brightness to 100%, and the three data series are what I see if I place the light meter over a pure white, gray, and black area on the screen.

Is this a problem that is likely caused by the screen backlight, the inverter, or the cable?

Comment: Keep the above test, hook up a different monitor and do the same test on a different monitor. What is the result?

Comment: I will at the first chance I get.  What are the possible outcomes of such a test and how would those trace back to a specific problem?

Comment: I have not seen such flickering and that is why I suggest another monitor to try

Comment: Ok, the laptop has only thunderbolt 3 ports, so I had to purchase a thunderbolt to HDMI adapter, should be here in a couple of days.

If the external monitor displays the signal properly, what would that rule out?

Comment: If the external monitor displays without flickering then it is the laptop monitor. If both flicker, it could be the GPU or associated drivers.

Comment: Thank you. And how can I differentiate between the LCD and the inverter?

Comment: That is really hard to do. I think the inverter will either work or not work. I have not seen one flicker. Also LCD screens are very old now. Everything recent is LED.

Comment: Put probes on the inverter output and patch to an oscilloscope.

Comment: It looks like annoying flicker on the boost regulator for the backlight.  Does it reduce with backlight levels?

Comment: Hi Tony, I actually contacted Acer again, and they agreed to look at it again with the graphs I sent them, and they offered to pay for shipping, so I couldn't turn that down, so I won't be able to check anything for the next week or so.  But last I (visually) checked, the flicker was still there, even with decreasing backlight levels.  I didn't see any flicker down past 30% or so (I don't know if that is because the problem isn't as bad at that level or because my eyes couldn't detect it.